# NBAndroid - NoClassDefFoundError when trying to use an external jar

Tags: android, plugins, netbeans, ant, reference

I am using the NBAndroid plugin for NetBeans. I need to add an external jar to my android project, so I'm doing this by copying the jar to the libs folder, located at my project root folder.

So, I add there, and reference it in my code. When I run the project, I get an exception:

`ERROR  AndroidRuntime  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pkt.java.api.WsControl`

I have tried all solutions that I've found from SO, but most of them are from 2 or 3 years ago, and the way we reference the plugins has changed since then, and those solutions no longer seem to work.

The jar I'm trying to reference is from a Java Class Library project.

Answer (score 1):

Just try removing the jar and add it once again. I had this problem and had it corrected it right away. If this too doesn't work try getting another copy of the jar and add it to your project.

Comment: Well, tried this lots of times. Didn't work. I don't get it, what's the problem?

Comment: Did you try getting another copy.